# How to check a dataset belongs to another dataset

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have one dataset which contains Student Fee Structure of a single FeeID as mentioned below:

```
        FeeID   Amount    FeeItem             Type
      *---------------------------------------------*
        10      7500      Admission Fee        T
        10      900       Annual Fee           T
        10      150       Application Fee      T
        10      850       Boy's Uniform        T
        10      50        Computer Fee         R
```

For example I have another dataset having following data:

```
        FeeID   Amount    FeeItem             Type
      *---------------------------------------------*
        9       8500      Admission Fee        T
        9       950       Annual Fee           T
        9       150       Application Fee      T
        9       850       Boy's Uniform        T
        9       50        Computer Fee         R
        11      7500      Admission Fee        T
        11      900       Annual Fee           T
        11      150       Application Fee      T
        11      850       Boy's Uniform        T
        11      50        Computer Fee         R
```

I want to check whether the set comprising of last three columns belongs to another dataset that contains data of all Fee Structures where FeeID may vary. Actual I want to retrieve matching FeeID having same Fee Structure.

In the above example if I search for the first one in the second it will return **True** and matching FeeID will be **11**.

Comment: DataSet is not a synonym for DataTable.

Comment: You want to check if all values of all fields in all rows are the same in two different Datatables? Is the order important?

Comment: Do you want to compare a subset of the table, for example  grouped by FeeID(because they are always 10) with another table or must all rows be the same? What means _"I want to retrieve matching FeeID having same Fee Structure. "_?

Comment: That means give me FeeID having same fee structure as the fee structure of given Fee ID (i.e. 10 in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve this issue. The following is my function. I am using the function **TablesEqual** as provided by **Tim Schmelter**. The function will return a valid **FeeID** which is a positive integer else -1 if no match is found.

```
private int MatchFeeID(DataTable Dt)
{
  DataTable mainDt = bl.GetDataSet("Select * From FeeMaster"); //assume this is a function that will return all the fee structures from database.

  var fids = (from row in mainDt.AsEnumerable().Distinct()
            group row by row.Field<string>("fid") into rowGroup
            select new
            {
              fid = rowGroup.Key
            });

  foreach (var fid in fids)
  {
    string id = fid.fid;

    DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable t2 = new DataTable();

    DataRow[] dr1 = mainDt.Select(String.Format("fid = '{0}'", id));

    t1 = dr1.CopyToDataTable();
    t2 = Dt;

    bool res = TablesEqual(t1, t2, 0, 1);
    if (res) return Convert.ToInt32(id);
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to initialize the DataTables(the constructor could be expensive). The first table is  initialized by `dr1.CopyToDataTable` and the second by `DT`. Apart from that it's, my method looks with `SequenceEquals` of `ItemArray` of every row equals. That works only if the columns are also in the same order. Do you need an approach that compares the fields independent to the column-order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/fb7bfe7f-2315-4107-ada1-7fb3396959d4) trick

```
Dataset ds1
DataSet ds2
DataSet dest;
dest.Merge(ds1);
dest.AcceptChanges();
dest.Merge(ds2);
diff = destination.GetChanges()
```

and check if diff is empty

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I've made ade some improvements to below code. Following `DataTable.IndexOf(otherTable)` extension method checks if a table is a subset of another table.

You can pass column names that you want to ignore in the comparison. The order of the columns does not matter but the order of `DataRows`(the subset must have the same order of rows).

It returns -1 when no equal subset of `DataRows` was found or the first index in the main-table(`this` in the extension) where the equal subset starts.

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOf(this DataTable tblMain, DataTable tblSub, params String[] ignoreColumns)
    {
        if (tblMain == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tblMain");
        if (tblSub.Rows.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("tblSub must not be empty", "tblSub");

        if (tblSub.Rows.Count > tblMain.Rows.Count)
            return -1;

        IEnumerable<String> relevantColumnNames = tblSub.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
            .Except(ignoreColumns)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (String colName in relevantColumnNames)
            if (!tblMain.Columns.Contains(colName))
                return -1;

        for (int mainRowIndex = 0; tblMain.Rows.Count - mainRowIndex >= tblSub.Rows.Count; mainRowIndex++)
        {
            // check if current window is equal to tblSub
            bool allRowsAreEqual = true;
            for (int windowIndex = mainRowIndex; windowIndex < tblSub.Rows.Count + mainRowIndex; windowIndex++)
            {
                DataRow currentMain = tblMain.Rows[windowIndex];
                DataRow currentSub = tblSub.Rows[windowIndex - mainRowIndex];
                bool allFieldsAreEqual = relevantColumnNames.All(colName =>
                    Object.Equals(currentMain[colName], currentSub[colName]));
                if (!allFieldsAreEqual)
                {
                    allRowsAreEqual = false;
                    break; // continue with next window in main-table
                }
            }
            if (allRowsAreEqual)
                return mainRowIndex;
        }
        // no equal window found in main-table
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Your sample data:

```
var TblSub = new DataTable();
var TblMain = new DataTable();
TblSub.Columns.Add("FeeID", typeof(int));
TblSub.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
TblSub.Columns.Add("FeeItem", typeof(string));
TblSub.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(char));
TblMain.Columns.Add("FeeID", typeof(int));
TblMain.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
TblMain.Columns.Add("FeeItem", typeof(string));
TblMain.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(char));

TblSub.Rows.Add(10, 7500, "Admission Free", 'T');
TblSub.Rows.Add(10, 900, "Annual Fee", 'T');
TblSub.Rows.Add(10, 150, "Application Free", 'T');
TblSub.Rows.Add(10, 850, "Boy's Uniform", 'T');
TblSub.Rows.Add(10, 50, "Computer Free", 'R');

TblMain.Rows.Add(9, 8500, "Admission Free", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(9, 950, "Annual Fee", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(9, 150, "Application Free", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(9, 850, "Boy's Uniform", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(9, 50, "Computer Free", 'R');
TblMain.Rows.Add(10, 7500, "Admission Free", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(11, 900, "Annual Fee", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(11, 150, "Application Free", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(11, 850, "Boy's Uniform", 'T');
TblMain.Rows.Add(11, 50, "Computer Free", 'R');
```

You can use it in this way:

```
int firstIndex = TblMain.IndexOf(TblSub, "FeeID");
if (firstIndex == -1)
    Console.Write("Second table does not contain first table");
else
    Console.Write("Second table does contain first table at row-index " + firstIndex);
```

Output is:

> Second table does contain first table at row-index 5

---

**old approach**:

You could use following method which checks whether or not two DataTables are equal.

You need to add `using System.Linq` for [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx). If you cannot use Linq, use loops.

```
static bool TablesEqual(DataTable table1, DataTable table2, params int[] skipColumns)
{
    if (table1.Rows.Count != table2.Rows.Count)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var array1 = table1.Rows[i].ItemArray
            .Where((obj, index) => !skipColumns.Contains(index));
        var array2 = table2.Rows[i].ItemArray
            .Where((obj, index) => !skipColumns.Contains(index)); ;
        if (!array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You just have to pass the indices of the columns you want o ignore, like:

```
bool allEqual = TablesEqual(t1, t2); // all equal
bool equalIgnore0 = TablesEqual(t1, t2, 0); // ignore first column
bool equalIgnore0and2 = TablesEqual(t1, t2, 0, 2); // ignore first and third column
```

Comment: Hi Tim, please check my last comment. This is not the exact solution what I want. I am not checking entire row but all other columns except the first one i.e FeeID. Order is also very important.

Comment: @Mahbub: Edited my answer. Since i'm comparing every row, the order is taken into account.

Comment: Remember number of rows in the first table is always less than the second table. So, I think the first **if** condition is not applicable here.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have elaborated my problem by giving detailed example. Please check again.

Comment: @Mahbub: Edited my answer in case somebody else is looking for a `DataTable.IndexOf(otherTable)` method.